# Bootstrap Pagination is removing href, making links unclickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have setup my pagination exactly how bootstrap pagination examples are given. Everything works except the links. Apparently the Jquery script removes the `href="link"` from the `<a>` tag.

This is what my php script generates in the html without the pagination script

```
<div id="alphabet">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/retailers.php">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="/retailers.php?letter=0-9" >0-9</a></li>
        <li><a href="/retailers.php?letter=A" >A</a></li>
        <li><a href="/retailers.php?letter=B" >B</a></li>   </ul>
</div>
```

This is what the pagination script does to my pagination links, as you can see it takes the links out:

```
<div id="alphabet" class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">&lt;</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">2</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a data-original-title="" title="">3</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">4</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">5</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">&gt;</a></li>
        <li><a data-original-title="" title="">&gt;&gt;</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

This is a screenshot of the my pagination with the script, as you can see it displays them exactly like the examples on the pagination site:

[image: pagination]

This is the options javascript I am using:

```
    var options = {
        currentPage: 3,
        totalPages: 10,
        useBootstrapTooltip:true
        bootstrapTooltipOptions: {
            html: true,
            placement: 'bottom'
        }
    }
    $('#alphabet').bootstrapPaginator(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
pageUrl: function(type, page, current){
   return "http://example.com/list/page/"+page;
}
```

I think you should adapt the code to get the letter instead of the page; you probably can do that with data-attributes.